# Moving and renaming image from one folder to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, save

I have two folders as part of my project, in the folder "Images" is a file called "FingerprintScan.jpg". What I am trying to do is fetch this file and then save it in my other folder called "FingerPrints".

The code I am using does not throw any errors and as far as I can tell should logically work however nothing happens.

```
string fileName = "FingerprintScan.JPG";
string newfilename = TextBoxUsername.Text + LabelStudentID.Text + ".JPG";
string appPath1 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Images\";
string appPath2 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"FingerPrints\";

string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(appPath1, fileName);
string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(appPath2, newfilename);

System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
```

I have tried playing around and using `@"~\Images\` and `@"Images` but had no luck.

Comment: Did you debug your application? Do you get a correct path in appPath1 variable and appPath2 variable?

Comment: debug your program and see paths and match with your physical path is it same

Comment: also check source file name

Comment: Try to check if files exist. Also, did you set "Copy to Output Directory" for the files you're trying to copy (in the *Properties* window)? Without that files from your project are not copied to the output directory.

Comment: Turns out it has been saving them to the file location now however it is saving it as a file type: file rather than jpg. This is something I will work on fixing however thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this combination and make sure your directory name and source file name match with the physical directory and file

```
string appPath1 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Images";
string appPath2 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "FingerPrints";
```

Comment: When I try this nothing happens, no new file in folder or error

Comment: `Path.Combine` automatically takes care of backward slash at the end. I'm not sure how it is different from what OP mentioned.